# Python FTP code sample

Tags: python, ftp

I need to upload the same local file into different destination file names on an FTP server. Not an expert of Python doing such function. Using Python 2.7 and any good code examples are appreciated. Thanks.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: You could search for examples by using google for, guess what, _python ftp upload_

Comment: Or, you could search the Python library docs and look at the examples for ftplib...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you started:

```
from ftplib import FTP    

hosts = [('10.1.0.1', 'abc', '123'), ('10.1.0.2', 'abc', '123')]
local_file = r'/my_folder/my_file.txt'
remote_file = 'my_file.txt'

for host, name, password in hosts:
    f = FTP(host, name, password)
    f.cwd('my_remote_folder')

    with open(local_file, 'rb') as f_local:
        f.storbinary('STOR {}'.format(remote_file), f_local)

    print "{} - done".format(host)
    f.quit()
```

This will upload `my_file.txt` from a single source location to each host in the `hosts` list. It uploads the file to the same location on each server.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your code, wondering why you put an additional `r` before  `/my_folder/my_file.txt`? Thanks.

Comment: Another question is, how to decide the value of `my_remote_folder`, is it relative directory to FTP root? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Martin, mark your reply as an answer. I tried your code and find a new issue here, and appreciate for your help in advance, and we can discuss in the new thread => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953563/ftp-upload-issue-in-python

Comment: Yes the remote folder is relative to the ftp root. If you sign in manually using ftp on the command line you would be able to see the starting folder.

Comment: @MartinEvans - I am looking at the ftplib code (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f6e5972fa984c10d47694973db1c91c6486d654a/Lib/ftplib.py#L354) but can't figure out how this connection is closed. Can you help me by pointing to the line that closes the socket?

Comment: AFAIR [`f.quit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.quit) should correctly close the connection. An extra call to `f.close()` should not be needed.