# FTP upload issue in Python

Tags: python, ftp

I am trying to upload a file to a remote server using Python 2.7, but when I run the script, the file on the remote FTP server is always called `test_0test_` on remote FTP server, rather than `test_0_13.pic.jpg` as I would expect. Any ideas?

```
from ftplib import FTP

hosts = [('1.2.3.4', 'admin', '12345')]
local_file = r'/Users/foo/Downloads/13.pic.jpg'
remote_file_base_name_prefix = 'test_'
counter = 0
remote_file_base_name_suffix='_13.pic.jpg'

for host, name, password in hosts:
    f = FTP(host, name, password)
    f.cwd('Input')

    print remote_file_base_name_prefix+str(counter)+remote_file_base_name_suffix

    with open(local_file, 'rb') as f_local:
        f.storbinary('STOR {}'.format(remote_file_base_name_prefix+str(counter)+remote_file_base_name_prefix), f_local)

    print "{} - done".format(host)
    f.quit()
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: I am unclear about the question - the file is always called `test_0test_` on the remote server?

Comment: @mprat, yes this is what I mean. Appreciate for your ideas and vote up. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you just had a typo in your code:

```
f.storbinary('STOR {}'.format(remote_file_base_name_prefix+str(counter)+remote_file_base_name_prefix), f_local)
```

should be

```
f.storbinary('STOR {}'.format(remote_file_base_name_prefix+str(counter)+remote_file_base_name_suffix), f_local)
```

Comment: Thanks mprat, your solution works for me and vote up. Mark as answered as well. :)